# How to set the authority key identifier using powershell New-SelfSignedCertificate

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, pki, self-signed

```
    New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=me.com, OU=ounit, O=company, L=state, C=country" -FriendlyName "me.com" 
     -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -KeyLength 4096 -KeyUsage DigitalSignature,KeyEncipherment 
       -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddDays(1024)  -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My 
        -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}CA=false") -KeyExportPolicy Exportable
```

I am working from the command above and trying to get this property set on the certificate : [image]

I tried the following and got errors:

```
-TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}CA=false","2.5.29.35={2.5.29.14}")
```

I know that with a self signed certificate Authority Key Identifier KeyID will be assigned to the
Subject Key Identifier in a self signed certificate, but what is the correct way to go about doing
this. Microsoft's Documentation doesn't clearly state:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

And I haven't been able to find any specific assignments through searching.

Comment: I have to ask - why?  AKI is only mandatory on certs _issued_ by an RFC 5280 compliant CA.  A self-signed cert doesn't require it (it's a 'may').  A Microsoft Root CA's cert doesn't have this, nor do commercial CA certs (not the ones I've checked anyway).  OpenSSL can do this, and I've noticed that PrimeKey can too, but that doesn't mean it has to be done.  Of course, if you must do this, then so be it...

Comment: Yes it is a requirement sadly from a client. I know it is available with openssl but still trying to get it done with powershell as there are some compatibility issues with AES256 and the server to be used.

Comment: If you get nowhere with PS, you can always install OpenSSL on that same machine and generate your self-signed cert with that, before importing it into the Windows cert store.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this issue with -**TextExtension** appears to have been left as an exercise for the reader.   But if you append the -**TestRoot** option instead, it will effectively "unhide" the `Authority Key Identifier` extension in the resulting code signing certificate.
As the documentation states, -**TestRoot** uses a built-in CA certificate with subject `CertReq Test Root` as the issuer of your code signing certificate.  For example, the following PowerShell command will create a code signing certificate that includes the otherwise missing extension:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName "Dev Test Code Signing AKI" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Type CodeSigningCert -FriendlyName Dev_Code_Signer_AKI -TestRoot
```

Here are properties of the resulting certificate, which includes the `Authority Key Identifier`extension:
[image]

This certificate is not technically self-signed, so its status is described as "okay" in the lower right.  The built-in issuer certificate, created as needed in the `Intermediate Certificate Authorities/Certificates` location, is self-signed and gives rise to the warning in the upper left. Here are its properties panels:

[image]

As hinted in the upper left, if you export this certificate, and subsequently import it to the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates` location, your code signed applications will become verifiable at runtime on your local Windows system.  But you can also expand the scope of your testing by importing it to root CA stores on other systems including, for example, Windows, Linux and OpenJDK environments.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer seems to be good for AIA but you will probably soon need a CDP for CRLs.  The short answer is to find a certificate that was issued by this CA and lift the field values from it.  This example should demonstrate the process to do that for the AIA extension:

```
$cert = get-item cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint
$aia = $cert.Extensions | where-object { $_.oid.value -eq "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1"}
$aiab64 = [system.convert]::ToBase64String($aia)
$aia = $cert.Extensions | where-object { $_.oid.value -eq "2.5.29.31"}
$cdpb64 = [system.convert]::ToBase64String($cdp)

New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=me.com, OU=ounit, O=company, L=state, C=country" -FriendlyName "me.com" 
 -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -KeyLength 4096 -KeyUsage DigitalSignature,KeyEncipherment 
   -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddDays(1024)  -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My 
    -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={text}CA=false","1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1=$aiab64","2.5.29.31=$cdpb64") -KeyExportPolicy Exportable
```

Basically you add TextExtension fields with the OID set to the base64 representation of the URL (with no token). It does not seem to accept them when listed as a URL token even though that would seem to make sense.  I believe that has to do with ASN encoding complexities with this OID (it overlaps with OCSP).

You can try encoding the string yourself, but it is complicated and not easy to learn.

```
$s=[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("http://aia.yourdomain.example.com/CertEnroll/MyCA.crt")
[byte[]]$t=(0x2B,0x06,0x01,0x05,0x05,0x07,0x30,0x02) # Specific to AIA
$t=(6,$t.length)+$t+(0x86,$s.length)+$s
$t=(48,$t.length)+$t
$t=(48,$t.length)+$t
$aiab64=[Convert]::ToBase64String($t)
```

The first byte string may need to be [byte[]]$t=(0x2B,0x06,0x01,0x05,0x05,0x07,0x30,0x01) but I have not played with it enough to be sure.  And technically the RFC requires an LDAP URL to be the first one listed (which means more complexity because it has to encode multiple URL references, which this can't do as it is).  The CDP extension should be something like this:

```
$s=[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("http://crl.yourdomain.example.com/CertEnroll/MyCA.crl")
[byte[]]$t=(0x82,0x01,0x11,0xA0,0x82,0x01,0x0D)
$t=(15,$t.length)+$t+(0x86,$s.length)+$s
$t=(48,$t.length)+$t
$t=(48,$t.length)+$t
$cdpb64=[Convert]::ToBase64String($t)
```

You can look at some of the class documentation for libraries like BouncyCastle (http://rcardon.free.fr/websign/download/api-x509-ext/be/cardon/asn1/x509/extensions/CRLDistributionPoints.html) for more hints.  If you want to get really deep, you can install the PsPKI module and explore the ASN classes.  https://www.pkisolutions.com/apidocs/pki/html/T_SysadminsLV_Asn1Parser_Asn1Builder.htm